# Can I prioritize the same word differently in different rows of a FULLTEXT column?

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

I have a site search that works by extracting words from several fields of my `articles` table (`name`, `body`, `author`, `category`), and putting all of them in a separate search table with a single FULLTEXT column.

I want to improve the accuracy of the search so that words extracted from the `name` field have a higher relevance than the same words extracted from the `body` field of the `articles` table.

In other words, if article 1's `name` field contained "Foo" once and article 2's `body` field contained "Foo" twice, article 1 would still be more relevant.

Is there a way to do this? I'm not referring to boolean searching, I want to attach relevance to the actual column data, not the search string.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach weight to a keyword depending on from where it came. So give default weights to words in your table. And when you come up with a score in your query, multiple that score with the default weight you have.

Obviously, words from name part of your would have more default value.

Comment: What I mean to say is the same word should have different weight depending on where it came from. For instance, consider this psuedo mysql FULLTEXT column row data: 'fred:5 fred:1 fred:1'. That is to say that fred:5 came from the name field, and fred:1 appeared twice in the body.

Comment: unless you maintain this meta info somewhere in some table, there is no way to know where a word came from.

Comment: If we redesign your search table to have say two more columns say nameScore and bodyScore, then while inserting data into your search table you can put a namescore as word1_from_name*5+ word2_from_name*5 and so on. You similiarly calculate a bodyScore. This way you have two indicative scores of name and body. You can use these values to sort your final result.